# I lose my private key on my blockchain wallet

Tags: private-blockchains

Can you please tell me how can I get my blockchain private key. I want to sell my coins. Please help me.

Comment: Did you make a backup of your wallet?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! If you have a blockchain.info wallet you should contact their customer support, otherwise please see the linked answer above your question.

Answer (score 0):

look through all your devices that you accessed the wallet with- surely you made a copy of your private key somewhere
Only you had control of that ...
what service diod you use initially?
MEW or ? an exchange ?